# Something's special about /dev/fd/3

Tags: ls, file-descriptors

I've been trying to learn about file descriptors. When I type "ls -l /dev/fd/" I get

```
lrwx------ 1 me users 64 May  2 16:02 0 -> /dev/pts/5
l-wx------ 1 me users 64 May  2 16:02 1 -> /home/me/file
lrwx------ 1 me users 64 May  2 16:02 2 -> /dev/pts/5
lr-x------ 1 me users 64 May  2 16:02 3 -> /proc/31518/fd
```

/dev/fd/3 seems to be pointing to the current process. However, explanations of file descriptors I've seen, e.g.
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html, don't say there's anything special about /dev/fd/3 (and imply it's just like any /dev/fd/N for N > 3). What's going on here?

I've observed this on arch linux and ubuntu, but not on the solaris server I have an ssh account on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> /dev/fd/3 seems to be pointing to the current process.

Ie., `ls` itself (notice that pid won't exist afterward).  All of those actually pertain to the current process, as file descriptors are not global; there is not just a single 0, 1, and 2 for the whole system -- there's a separate 0, 1, and 2 for each process.

As Frederik Dweerdt notes, `/dev/fd` is a symlink. If you repeat your `ls` from different terminals, you'll notice links to different ptys.  These will match the output of the `tty` command.

In the `ls` example, I would imagine descriptor 3 is the one being used to read the filesystem.  Some C commands (eg, `open()`), which underpin the generation of file descriptors, guarantee the return of *"the lowest numbered unused file descriptor"* ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) -- note that low level open() is actually not part of Standard C). So they are recycled after being closed (if you open and close different files repeatedly, you will get 3 as an fd over and over again).

If you want a clue about how they come to exist, here's a snippet of C code using `opendir()`, which you'll probably find in the source for ls:

```
// open directory for reading
DIR *dh = opendir(".");
// print the fd of the directory handle to standard out:
printf("fd: %d\n", dirfd(dh));
closedir(dh);
```

Run as is, the fd will be 3, since that is the lowest unused descriptor (0, 1, and 2 already exist).

Answer (score 14):

`/dev/fd/3` is not a standard descriptor (edit: assignment). It (edit: having more than 0, 1 and 2) is specific to your case (`ls`). You can run ls through strace to understand what happens:

```
strace -e trace=openat,readlink ls -l /dev/fd/
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/fd/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
readlink("/dev/fd/0", "/dev/pts/0", 65) = 10
readlink("/dev/fd/1", "/dev/pts/0", 65) = 10
readlink("/dev/fd/2", "/dev/pts/0", 65) = 10
readlink("/dev/fd/3", "/proc/28401/fd", 65) = 14
```

`ls` is to display the content of `/dev/fd` which is the same like `/proc/self/fd`. `ls` has to open the directory in order to read its entries. `/dev/fd/3` is just the file descriptor to this directory.

Other programs don't have `/dev/fd/3`:

```
start cmd:> sleep 100 &
[1] 28414

ec:0   17:28:10  hl@inno:~/.wine/drive_c
start cmd:> ls -l /proc/28414/fd
insgesamt 0
crw------- 1 hl tty 136, 0 18. Apr 01:18 0
crw------- 1 hl tty 136, 0 18. Apr 01:18 1
crw------- 1 hl tty 136, 0 18. Apr 01:18 2
```

Comment: Maybe it is slightly misleading to say it is "not a standard descriptor. It is specific to your case..."?  3 is a normal file descriptor exactly like 0, 1, and 2, but 0, 1, and 2 have standard assignments (standard in, standard out, standard error) whereas 3 could be anything.  Note it is possible to use 0, 1, and 2 in the same way, but this would be considered a bad practice.

Comment: ^would be^ -> could be, since it's bound to happen if you, eg, `close(0)`.

Comment: If you already use fd 3, does ls choose a different fd?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Thy syscall `open()` uses the first free file descriptor. The calling application should not care about its number; that's why it is returned by the call.

Answer (score 7):

On Archlinux, `/dev/fd` is a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. What you're seeing is the `fd` directory of your `ls` command. And this command indeed opened the directory as file descriptor 3.

EDIT: BTW, a good way to understand what's going on is to use `strace`. You'll see the process opening the file descriptors.